# PowerShell equivalent of curl http://www.example.com/script.sh | bash -s <arguments>

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, arguments, user-data

How to run a remote script in PowerShell with arguments. 
For linux I'm using `curl http://www.example.com/script.sh | bash -s <arguments>`.

Is there a similar equivalent in PowerShell.

Use Case: User-Data script for Amazon EC2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll often find examples out there like this:

```
iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://domain/script.ps1')
```

[`iex` is an alias for `Invoke-Expression`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx) (think of it like `exec` or `eval` in some other languages).

The rest of it is creating a [`[System.Net.WebClient]` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx), which has a method to download the contents of a URL and return it as a string.

Comment: Thanks @briantist , can I pass arguments like `.. | bash -s <arguments>`

Comment: @Shan I don't think so, but you could possibly rework it by creating a `[ScriptBlock]` from the downloaded string and then using `Invoke-Command -ArgumentList` to execute it, but the script has to be written to use those params.

Comment: Got it, Thank you something like `&{param()...entire script here}`. Still not sure how to manage the restart to change hostname in windows